# How to sequentially call the same controller method without using async: false in client side?

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I need to call the `"CodeListLookup"` method which is in controller twice with different value while loading the page in client side. Currently it works as expected but not for the first time? I solved this problem using by adding `async: false`. But I need an alternative solution to overcome this issue? Below I added the Javascript code?

Appreciate your help...

**JavaScript:**

```
 RepairEstimatePriorities: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: '@Url.Action("CodeListLookup", "GeneralData", new { Area = "Settings" })/?codeListType=PriorityType',
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            type: "GET"
                        }
                    }
                }),

                RepairEstimateServiceTypes: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            type: "GET",
                            datatype: "json",
                            url: '@Url.Action("CodeListLookup", "GeneralData", new { Area = "Settings" })/?codeListType=ServiceType',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        }
                    }
                }),
```

**Below Error am getting:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function
```